# How can I display a long TextView height in a ListView row?

Tags: java, android, listview, textview, android-linearlayout

I have a ListView that looks like this:
[image]

Notice how the TextView is getting cut off with elipses. How can I make sure the entire TextView is visible inside of the ListView?

Here is my XML for the row (the textview is called `bodyTextView`):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:padding="4px">
      <ImageView android:id="@+id/avatarImageView"
          android:layout_width="48px"
          android:layout_height="48px"/>
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingLeft="4px">
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center_vertical">
              <TextView android:id="@+id/usernameTextView"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="left"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:ellipsize="end"
                  android:textColor="#444444"
                  android:padding="0px"/>

              <TextView android:id="@+id/bodyTextView"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:singleLine="false"
                  android:textColor="#666666"
                  android:maxLines="5"
                  android:ellipsize="end"/>
          <TextView android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:singleLine="true"/>
          </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set ellipsize="none". Also, be sure to specify maxLines big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ellipsize="none" won't affect the width of the element.

To get an element to display its full contents in a LinearLayout, you need to set its layout_width or layout_height (whichever is applicable) to "wrap_content", and then ensure that other elements in the LinearLayout will not take up the space first. Even with this option, a singleLine TextView will still ellipsize once it fills the width of the surrounding layout, of course.

How do you make sure other elements play nice? Make sure they are not **also** set to a fill_* option or wrap_content. An easy way to display several TextViews with one taking up all the space it needs and the others playing nice is this: Set the primary one to a layout_width of "wrap_content" with a layout_weight of "0" (this is the default weight, you do not need to set it), and then set the others to a layout_width of "0dip" with a layout_weight of "1". This will give the primary TextView to the layout with a set width matching the content, and the other TextViews with an effective width of zero. The layout will then see the layout_weights and resize the other TextViews to take up the remaining space.